# How to keep the rest of the data when update an array inside an object?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my case, I want to update an array inside an object.

```
obj{ array1: 1, 2, 3, 4, array2 : 1, 2, 3, 4}
{...obj, obj.array1: 5}
```

While I used this code, all the array1 data had gone.

My goal is to push 5 in array1 and keeping all the data.

Comment: `{ ...obj, array1: [...obj.array1, 5] }`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! But it returns [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,\"21\",\"22\"] what does the slash mean? @ 
Tom

Comment: Can you post your exact data? And what you're doing to print that... are you calling `JSON.stringify()` or something? The `\"` is escaping a string, so your array is a bunch of numbers and a few strings

Comment: Thanks Bro! I understand now much better.  All 
 I need is to use Number to convert those string, right?@Tom